# How to retrieve div tag and question mark symbol from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to retrieve div tag from mysql using php

I inserted div tag to mysql using `mysql_real_escape_string($test)` successfully,But I have problem when i retrieve the same field from mysql using the same `mysql_real_escape_string(field)`,Please give Solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

Use the php function `stripslashes(field)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 //mysql_real_escape_string() is only used in inserting special chars like ' and " by escaping it.it puts \ before ' or " to be \' or \"
 //it is very handy also in handling injection against hackers
 //conclusion mysql_real_escape_string() only used in insert queries.

 //if you want to retrieve it from db follow this example
 $connected=mysql_connect($your_db_host,$your_db_uname,$your_db_pass);
 if(!$connected){
     die(mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db($your_db_name) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("SET CHARSET utf8") or die(mysql_error());
 $sql="SELECT your_field FROM your_table WHERE id='".intval($_GET["your_id"])."' ";
 //always use intval with integers to prevent injection
 //assuming the id is in _GET array
 $results=mysql_query($sql);
 if(!$results){
    echo 'no data found!';
     //die(mysql_error());
 }else{
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)){
      echo "my filed value : ".stripslashes($row["your_field"]);
      //stripslashes() is used to remove \" and \' ==> to be ' and " only without slashes
      echo "<br/>";
      //if your field contains <html> tags or <div> the browser will understand it automatically and translates it
     //notice if you need to echo html content in <input> field for example ==> you need to htmlentities($the_out) before print it.
     //for example <input id='myinput' name='myinput' value='<?php echo htmlentities($row["your_field"]);?>' />
     //why ? because if your $row["your_field"] contains html tags within -> it will break the input structure
    //it would be something corrupt like
    // <input id='myinput' name='myinput' value='<div><p><strong>blablabla</strong>blablabla</p></div>' /> 
   }
 }
```